# Speech Recognition not working when i am calling the function in flask

Tags: python, flask, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am new to Flask and the task in hand is to use use speech_recognition library and create a simple web page where i can let user ask his query using speech.

Below is the code snippet for speech recognition python script(audio.py)

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

def speech2text():

    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("speak now")

        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            #print('you said : {}'.format(text))
            return ('you said : {}'.format(text)) 
        except:
            return("Sorry your audio is not clear. Please try again")
```

I am importing this python script into my Flask code as below. But when i run the Flask code it is always going in except block and returning **Sorry your audio is not clear. Please try again**. But when I run audio.py it does the job.

```
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS

from bert import QA
from audio import speech2text

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

model = QA("model")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    text = speech2text()
    return text
    #return render_template('home.html')
```

Comment: catch the exception and print it - `except Exception as e: print(e)` hard to know how to fix it without knowing what the exception actually is